# Inserting values from for loop into sqlite using python?

Tags: python, sqlite

is it possible to insert a series of values into a sqlite database ?? using for loop or any other method?

```
for i in range(100000, 100010):  
    cursor.execute("""insert into users values(%d, '', '02adcec2263d2127269fcd769c33f029', 1,         1, 0, 0, 0)""", i)
```

Comment: why not try it and see for yourself?

Comment: @Bryan: i tried.. but got an operational error. so thought i might've missed something..

Comment: "got an operational error"?  Really?  Why isn't that part of your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just iterate over values you want to insert and run the sql command with values you want. But please don't use formatting for building sql command and rather use binding.

I belive this line should a little different:

```
'''insert into users values(%d, '', '02adcec2263d2127269fcd769c33f029', 1,         1, 0, 0, 0)''' % i
```

Comment: ok.. i'll try and learn the differences between formatting and binding :) meanwhile, "OperationalError: near "%": syntax error" i get this and as a beginner, i have no clue :(